# Django group by a pair of values

Tags: django

I would want to do a group by with a pair of values in django.

Consider I have the following model,

class Vehicle:

```
vehicle_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
version_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
name=models.CharField(max_length=8096)
description=models.CharField(max_length=8096)
```

vehicle_id is not the primary key since there can be multiple rows in the table with the same vehicle_id but with different version_id

Now I would want to get the latest versions of all the vehicles.

```
select * from (
          select vehicle_id, MAX(version_id) as MaxVersion from Vehicle group by vehicle_id
              ) s1
JOIN Vehicle s2
on s2.vehicle_id = s1.vehicle_id AND s2.version_id=s1.MaxVersion;
```

Tried to represent this in Django ORM like below,

```
feed_max_version = (
        self
        .values("vehicle_id")
        .annotate(max_version=Max("version_id"))
        .order_by("vehicle_id")
    )
q_statement = Q()

for pair in feed_max_version:
     q_statement |= Q(vehicle_id__exact=pair["vehicle_id"]) & Q(
             version_id=pair["max_version"]
        )
return self.filter(q_statement)
```

But this seems less efficient and takes long time to load. I am not very keen on having raw SQL since I would not be able to add any more queryset methods on top of it.

Comment: The original SQL contains a subquery; you need to do the same in the ORM version; see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions).